# C IDE for Debian Embedded Development

Tags: linux, ide, c

Can you suggest a C IDE for Debian OS? I am new to developing on linux OS's, I'ved used Xcode on Mac OS which has been very good. The development I am doing is Embedded C for debian OS so if there are IDE's relevant to this on debian I'd be interested.

I think there is eclipse for Debian but I am looking for other suggestions.

Comment: We will need much more information to give ***good*** recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. The better you describe your requirements (e.g. what features you need, what features would be nice-to-have optionals, and what you do *not* want to be there), the better answers can match those :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

emacs will work, although I prefer geany which has status, compiler, messages, scribble, and terminal windows along with all the code/file windows.

It has a compiler, a linker, ability to set all the options for both compiling and building

It has the ability to run the executable in a (temporary) terminal.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) on a wide variety platforms - it works with a variety of compilers, including cross compilers, and you can configure for remote debugging - usually important on developing embedded systems.  The exact details for remote debugging vary between compilers & debuggers.